# Capture word corrected by Google search

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm looking to capture a word corrected by Google search. I tried based on the code below, generating a search with the words misspelled "pithon" but I couldn't get the word "python" suggested in the "Including results for:" Follow the code snippet and part of the page source where I want to get the word:

---

```
q="pithon"
q = str(str.lower(q)).strip()
url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + urllib.parse.quote(q)
html = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
ans = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'class' : 'spell'})
print(ans)
```

---

```
<p class="gqLncc card-section" aria-level="3" role="heading">
<span class="gL9Hy d2IKib">Including results for:</span>
<a class="gL9Hy" href="/search?client=firefox-b-d&amp;channel=crow2&amp;sxsrf=ALeKk03QpAwp78UNkWeDgzZYYpT73zlopg:1592965054382&amp;q=python&amp;spell=1&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=2ahUKEwiFytKhsZnqAhWVIbkGHUPEAsAQBSgAegQIDRAq">
<b>
<i>python</i>
</b>
</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get correct result of the page, specify `User-Agent` string. Alson, add parameter `hl=en` to get english version of the page:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


q="pithon"

parameters = {'q': q, 'hl': 'en'}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0'}
url = "http://www.google.com/search"
html = requests.get(url, params=parameters, headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

did_you_mean = soup.select_one('span:contains("Did you mean:")')
if did_you_mean:
    print(did_you_mean.find_next('i').text)
```

Prints:

```
python
```

Answer (score 0):

A complimentary answer to [Andrej Kesely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62563729/15164646) to scrape corrected word and a link using `css` selectors.

*Note that Andrej said that his solution works for English pages only. Solution below works on other languages as well.*

Code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  'q': 'londebn',
  'hl': 'en',
  'gl': 'us',
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=', headers=headers, params=params).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

correct_me = soup.select_one('a.gL9Hy').text
correct_me_link = soup.select_one('a.gL9Hy')['href']

print(f'Corrected word: {correct_me}')
print(f'https://www.google.com{correct_me_link}')

# output:
'''
Corrected word: london
https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gl=us&q=london&spell=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwigm4Cgqq3xAhUNXc0KHUNpBOgQBSgAegQIARAw
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerpApi to get corrected word. It's a paid API with a free trial of 5,000 searches. Check out the [Playground](https://serpapi.com/playground?q=londebn&gl=us&hl=en).

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

params = {
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "londebn",
  "google_domain": "google.com",
  "gl": "us",
  "hl": "en"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

corrected_word = results['search_information']['spelling_fix']
print(corrected_word)

# output:
'''
london
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.